# I'm trying to increase a value when clicking and value returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html, css, nan

I've tried a lot of stuff, however I don't know any JavaScript. All of the JavaScript in the code is copied from stack overflow and other sources. The only thing I know how to use is HTML and I'm still very new. (it might also include some CSS which I also don't know at all)

The `<!--<button id="bigButton" onclick="bigBottlePress()"><img src="Images/BigBottle.png"></button>-->` is a failed thing so ignore it lol.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bottle Clicker</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href=# onclick="bigBottlePress()"><img src="Images/BigBottle.png" height="500"></a>
<!--<button id="bigButton" onclick="bigBottlePress()"><img src="Images/BigBottle.png"></button>-->
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="hydrationLevelDisplay" placeholder="Hydration Level: " disabled style= text-align:center>
<script>
    var hydrationLevel = 0
    function bigBottlePress() {
            var hydrationLevel = hydrationLevel + 1
            document.getElementById("hydrationLevelDisplay").value = "Hydration Level: " + hydrationLevel;
            document.title = "Hydration Level: " + hydrationLevel;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `var` in `var hydrationLevel = hydrationLevel + 1`.

Comment: You are declaring two variables with the same name.  Remove the `var` in front of  the second declaration of `hydrationLevel`

Comment: might as well just
`hydrationLevel++;`

Comment: I wasn't trying to declare another variable. I was just trying to edit the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already declared `hydrationLevel` outside function, so don't need to redclare it. Just change,

```
var hydrationLevel = hydrationLevel + 1
```

to

```
hydrationLevel = hydrationLevel + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been trying to figure it out for an hour!

Comment: Surely this should be voted to close as either a duplicate or a typo.... rather than answered?!?

Comment: @devlincarnate you know better does makes sense

Comment: I'm just horrible at JS and was trying to edit the variable. I thought I needed to put var again.

Answer (score 1):

create a button -> id:btn
create a result div or p or h1 -> id:hydrationLevel

select the button, add event listener

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', incrementLevel)
let hydrationCount = 0;

function incrementLevel() {
 hydrationCount += 1;
 document.getElementById('hydrationLevel').textContent = hydrationCount;
}
```

I'd encourage you to use event listeners this way. not inline that's why I provided this solution.

Comment: I haven't heard of event listeners I'll look into it thanks!